# Django Upload File, Analyise Conents and write to DB or update form

Tags: django, django-models

I'm pretty new to Django, Trying to get my grips with it, and expand what I think its capable of doing, and maybe one of you more intelligent people here can point me in the right direction.

I'm basically trying to build a system similar to a so called "Asset Management" system, to track software version of a product, so when an engineer updates the software version, they run a script which gathers all the information (Version, Install date, Hardware etc), which is stored in a .txt file, The engineer then comes back to the website and upload this .txt file for that customer, and it automatically updates the fields in the form, or directly to the database.

While, I've search a bit on here for concepts, I haven't been able to find something similar (Maybe my search terms aren't correct?), and wanted to ask if anyone knows, what I'm doing is even feasible, or am I lost down the rabbit hole of limitations :) Maybe its not do-able within Django, Any suggestions on how I should approach such a problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is doable both in the form and post-submit of a form or file upload.

In the form approach you'll want a live-reload of the form should the data come from a .txt file. That can be done with JavaScript. This will mean that the data will come from the text file and be input into the forms in the manner you define. This also means form validation will work as you want it to.

Another option is to require a txt file in a specified format, and parse it in the view, `form_valid()` for Class-Based Views, and `request.FILES[]` for function based views, and then perform all the required validations and then save the values to the database as the model instance.

Comment: Ah ok perfect, thank you for the feedback and advice, I will give it a go with your suggestion and let you know how I go.